# A specific type of tridiagonal matrix? Or just Strang's matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$

In a talk on positive definite matrices, [Prof. Strang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_Strang) mentions that he remembers the eigenvalues of the matrix above because ["These matrices are so important to figure them out."](https://youtu.be/vF7eyJ2g3kU?t=2495).

In [here](https://youtu.be/1DvlyNjfuzM), he says,

> So second derivatives should have a bigger place in calculus. Second, **my matrices**, which are like the linear algebra version of second derivatives, are in need in linear algebra. Everything comes out right with those guys.

I see that it is a [tridiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix), but I wonder if the $-1$ off-diagonals confer them a last name - are these

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
a & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & a & -1 \\
0 & -1 & a
\end{bmatrix}$$

arrangements a separate group of tridiagonal matrices? And why are they so important?

---

Incidentally, he derives them from the eigenvectors, which in turns he deducts by analogy of this difference of second differences to a second order differential equation [here](https://youtu.be/kIl6LsJuxqI?t=2480).

---

These are specific forms of [band matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20particularly%20matrix%20theory,more%20diagonals%20on%20either%20side.) and [Toeplitz matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix), and in his book [Linear Algebra and Its Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0030105676) he describes them as the first of "four families of matrices - simple and useful, absolutely basic" with the nondescript name $K_n.$ Their properties are:

1. Symmetric
2. Sparse
3. Banded (tridiagonal): Rapidly solved.
4. Constant diagonals: Shift or time invariance. Can be used as a highpass filter.
5. Second difference matrix.
6. Invertible
7. Positive definite

On page 66 and 67 he explains their value as the matrix formulation of a discretized problem of second derivatives as such:

The first difference is

$$\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}=\frac{u(x+\Delta x) - u(x - \Delta x)}{2 \Delta x}$$

and the second difference

$$\small\frac{\Delta^2 u}{\Delta x^2}=\frac{\left(u(x+\Delta x) - u(x)\right) -\left(u(x)-u(x-\Delta x)  \right)}{\Delta x^2}=\frac{u(x+\Delta x) - 2u(x)  +u(x- \Delta x)}{\Delta x^2}$$

and multiplying by $\Delta x^2,$

$$\small\begin{bmatrix}
2&-1&&\\-1&2&-1&&\\&-1&2&-1\\
&&-1&2&-1&&\\
&&&-1&2&-1&\\
&&&&-1&2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 \\u_2\\u_3\\u_4\\u_5\\u_6
\end{bmatrix}=h^2
\begin{bmatrix}f(h)\\f(2h)\\f(3h)\\f(4h)\\f(5h)\\f(6h)
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\Delta x= h,$ and the differential equation to solve of the form

$$-\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=f(x)$$

> the temperature distribution in a rod, for example, with ends fixed at 0 degrees and with a heat source $f(x).$

In other words the solution of a [Poisson's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation).

Comment: I don't know if $-1$ is important per se, but you could call it a symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix.

Comment: Any general property or use that would warrant the comment on the videoclip? Or is it just a reference to tridiagonal matrices in general?

Comment: They do arise frequently, e.g. in a discretisation of the second derivative.

Comment: They are Cartan matrices of root systems (or simple Lie algebras) of type $A_{n-1}$. Also IIRC their characteristic polynomials are closely related to Chebyshev polynomials. I guess I'm saying that I agree with Prof Strang.

Comment: Have a look at a question I asked some time ago (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1774670)

Comment: In particular the first matrix is diagonalized by the finite sine transform. See (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1880704)