# TextBook Fact Check: Transform $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\lambda y=0;\;\;\;y(0)=0,\;y'(1)=0$ into Integral Equation form

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Want to fact check the solution steps used by my textbook in transforming the above differential equation into an Integral Equation.

Here are the steps:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\lambda y=0; \;\;\; y(0)=0, \; y'(1)=0$$
The solution is $y=\sin \frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{2},\;\;\lambda={[\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}]}^2 \;\;\; n=1,2,3...$

Now the step I don't understand is the switch to $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=f(x)$

Under the boundary condition specified, they now solved further:
$$y=x\int_1^x f(u)du+\int_x^0uf(u)du$$
The Integral formulation becomes:
$$y(x)=\lambda\int_0^1K(x, u)y(u)du$$
Where:

$K(x, u)=x \;\;\;\;\; 0\leq x\leq u \;\;\;\;\; 1\leq u\leq x$

$K(x, u)=u \;\;\;\;\; u\leq x\leq1 \;\;\;\;\; x\leq u\leq0$

Where did they get it wrong. And what's the right step to take?

Answer (score 1):

Let us very slightly modify the expression you give:

$$\tag{1}y(x)=x g(x) -\int_0^xuf(u)du \ \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ \ \ g(x):=\int_1^x f(u)du$$

Let us differentiate it with respect to $x$:

$$\tag{2}y'(x)=g(x) + xg'(x) - xf(x)$$

Because $g'(x):=f(x)$, relationship (2) boils down to:

$$\tag{3}y'(x)=g(x)$$

Differentiating once more:

$$\tag{4}y''(x)=g'(x)=f(x),$$

what was desired.

Moreover, we retrieve the initial conditions $y(1)=y'(1)=0$. Here is how:

- Making $x=0$ in (1) gives: $y(1)= 0g(0) -\int_0^0uf(u)du=0.$
- Making $x=0$ in (3) gives $y'(1)=g(1)=\int_1^1f(u)du=0.$

I have not commented the rest. Do you agree with the transformation into the classical "kernel" $K$ formulation? (Caution : your last column has to be removed). A remark: $K$ can be written

$$K(x,t)=min(x,t).$$

Its relationship with the second derivative is well known: see my answer in (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1897846).

A question: I haven't understood what you call "wrong' in all this formulation.

Comment: I have slightly modified the las lines of my answer.

Comment: What I felt was wrong was the conversion of the equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\lambda y=0$ to the form $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=f(x) $. Perhaps you can help me clarify.

Comment: In fact, if you agree that transformation $y \rightarrow Y(x)=\int_0^1K(x, u)y(u)du$ is like integrating twice (with, in front, a minus sign), starting from $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\lambda y=0$ and integrating twice gives $y(x)=\lambda\int_0^1K(x, u)y(u)du.$

Comment: Can I ask you which textbook do you use ?

Comment: Actually use a course material prepared by my school. No standard textbook

Answer (score 0):

I have finally gotten it with the help of @JeanMarie

My confusion was the switch from $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\lambda y=0$$ to $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=f(x) $$

I've finally come to realise that $$f(x)$$ was equated to $$-\lambda y(x) $$
i.e. $f(x)=-\lambda y(x) $

The Integral form was then calculated for the equation $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=f(x)$

$$y(x)=\int_1^0K(x, u)f(u)du\;\;\;\;\;\; (1)$$
Note however that $f(x)=-\lambda y(x) $

Thus $$f(u)$$ transform into into $$-\lambda y(u) $$

And equation (1) becomes:

$$y(x)=\lambda\int_0^1K(x, u)y(u)du\;\;\;\;\;\; (2)$$

Where:

$K(x, u)=x \;\;\;\;\; 0\leq x\leq u \;\;\;\;\; 1\leq u\leq x$

$K(x, u)=u \;\;\;\;\; u\leq x\leq1 \;\;\;\;\; x\leq u\leq0$