# Complex analysis using Kronecker delta..

Tags: complex-analysis, kronecker-delta

I have some trouble with proving the formula below;

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin\Big(\frac{kr \pi}{n+1}\Big)\sin\Big(\frac{ks \pi}{n+1}\Big) = \frac{n+1}{2}\delta_{rs}$$

by making use of complex analysis for any $r, s=1, 2, 3, \ldots, n$.

To solve this, I wanted to use the Kronecker delta's property, $$\delta_{rs} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^ n{e}^{2\pi i \frac{k}{n} (r-s)}$$

So I changed the first formula using addition formulas for sinusoidal functions, 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2}\left[\cos\Big(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}(r-s)\Big)-\cos\Big(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}(r+s)\Big)\right]$$

I'm stuck in this situation. How can I get started..?

Comment: Did you try the $r=s$ case first? Then the Kronecker-$\delta$ is just zero and this case should be easier to prove.

Comment: I thought I did the case when r=s, but I think my solution is incomplete.. Oh, and if r=s, isn't the kronecker delta be 1?

Comment: It's 1, you're right. It is zero if $r \neq s$.

Comment: How can I get started..? I can't get any idea of it..,, quite difficult to me..

Comment: This issue is called "discrete orthogonality". Take a look at the answer I gave to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1880622)