# Find the limit of $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} x_n ^ 2 - 1, n \ge 1, x_1 = 1/3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I’ve already found that the limit $L = 1+\sqrt{3}$ or $L=1-\sqrt{3}$. Since this sequence does not totally an increasing sequence or decreasing sequence, it’s hard for me to except a root. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: I am commenting here on your previous question about maximisation of product knowing the sum, as I cannot do it directly (You have erased it). In the reference I gave https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1774670, I should have explicitly said that you have to look at Dickman's answer : it shows how your isuue is related to number $e$ in particular.

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks u so much <3

Comment: *Hint:* The sequence of odd-numbered terms is monotonic. So is the even-numbered one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* the limit exists, 
call it $x$.

Then $2x=x^2-2\implies x=\dfrac {2\pm\sqrt{4-4(1)(-2)}}{2(1)}=\dfrac {2\pm2\sqrt3}2=1\pm\sqrt3 $.

Note, $x_n\lt0\,,\forall n\gt1\implies x\le0$.  For $\vert x_n\vert\lt1\,,\forall n$.

Comment: Very appreciate. But Why abs(xn) < 1 in your second line?

Comment: $\vert x\vert\lt1\implies \frac12x^2\lt1\implies \vert\frac12x^2-1\vert\lt1$.

Comment: Yup! Understand!

Comment: @Chris Custer I'm sorry but your answer isn't rigorous. Two comments : 1) How an you say that $x_n < 0$ for all $n$ ? [First of all it is not true for $n=1$]... 2) How do you know that $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence ?

Comment: @JeanMarie   You're right.  I don't know if it's convergent.  It looks like it's negative (after the first term) though.